# Authentication with AWS Incognito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito

Thanks to [blog.kdgregory.com](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2016/12/server-side-authentication-with-amazon.html), i was able to use amazon cognito for authentication in a sample java application.

However, @KeithGregory used an aws SDK version: 1.11.60. In the latest version of aws SDK (1.11.205), most of the constructors (e.g. AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient) are now deprecated.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement aws cognito in a more recent version. The AWS documentation is not so clear on the implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general all of the old client constructors are deprecated in the newer AWS libraries.  You'll need to do something like:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = 
        AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().defaultClient();
```

This is the bare bones version - if you need to pass a different credentials provider or region you'll need to add some more parameters.  See [AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.html) and [AWSCognitoIdentityProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But i can a "client is immutable" error when i try to log in.  The trace is:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client is immutable when created with the builder.
 at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.checkMutability(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:920)

Comment: I figured it out. I was setting the region explicitly (with another deprecated method, setRegion) on the client. The right way to do this is to use withRegion while creating the client. This solved the problem: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).defaultClient();

Comment: @ayoalatishe AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder's function defaultClient is static and just returns standard().build(). I think what you wanted is AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();